# Can OneDrive be used as a continuous backup of the entire user directory?

Tags: windows-10, backup, onedrive, windows-backup

Last year, I nearly lost my computer. So I do have a physical back up, but I also have a lot of free space on onedrive. I was wondering if it is possible to automatically back up your entire personal user directory from one's computer to onedrive. It does give me options to automatically save documents, images and my desktop in onedrive, but not for my other files stored in my personal user directory. I tried making my personal user directory the onedrive directory, but it keeps making a onedrive folder in the personal user directory.

By personal user directory, I mean the folder located at C:/Users/{username}.

Comment: If you want dedicated backup, invest in dedicated backup, not a sync service.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by *user file*. Do you perhaps mean *user profile directory*, i.e. the folder at `C:\Users\<username>`? Please [edit] your question to update it.

Comment: I mean that indeed. I will edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CloudBerry Backup](https://www.cloudberrylab.com/backup.aspx) allows you to set up backup of any directories to your choice of many online cloud storage providers.

You need to make an account with the relevant cloud storage provider and give the details to the CloudBerry software, which then logs in and stores the data you have been requested to back up. It says it works with OneDrive, but I've only used it with Amazon Glacier.

[Easus](https://www.easeus.com/backup-recovery/backup-files-to-onedrive.html), [NovaBackup](http://novabackup.novastor.com/blog/how-to-use-onedrive-securely-backup-backup/) and [JungleDisk](https://www.jungledisk.com/blog/2016/07/20/how-to-backup-microsoft-onedrive/) also say they can do OneDrive backups, though I've not used them.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to specify which folders to sync in OneDrive settings. I'm using version 2018 (build 17.005.0107.0008). If I right click the onedrive icon and select settings and select choose folders under the Account tab, I can select which folders I want to sync (see the screenshot below). For my personal account, I can also select if I want to save desktop, documents and pictures to "This PC Only" or OneDrive under the Auto Save tab of settings.

[image]